# Code snippet save button should have a different label when updating

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-snippets

When working on a code snippet, a button labelled `Save & insert into post` is shown on the top-left side.

[image: screenshot]

I think this label is fine for *creating* a code snippet that hasn't been inserted into a question/answer yet. But when *updating* an existing code snippet, I feel that it would be better if it just read `Save`.

The word `insert` seems to imply that your updated code snippet will be added to the question/answer *again* (resulting in two code snippets), and I do a bit of a double-take every time I see it. (Or maybe I've just written one too many `INSERT INTO` SQL statements. )

A minor suggestion and not something I'll lose sleep over, but I'm curious to hear what others think.

Comment: Meh... seems like an insignificant issue to me.

Comment: I agree with @Tanner and the OP as well - minor suggestion. However, I'd be more interested to hear from the Stack team on how *difficult* this change would be. I get requests for this kind of thing daily at my job. In my environment - easy fix. Basically I could slap on a glorified `IF` statement on what shows on certain pages. For millions of users and thousands of tables like the Stack product - maybe not an easy fix. How difficult would a change like this be?